# Equivalent of PHP Die(): how to stop function's execution on server

Tags: meteor

I am building a Meteor application with some custom authentication in addition to the built-in `accounts` MDG package.
I want to have a function I call at the front of Meteor methods to verify authentication. If authentication fails, I would like to do the equivalent of PHP's `die()` function - return a message and stop execution.

I could always do something like this: `if(!checkAuth()) return "Not Authenticated"`, however it would be nice if I could just do `checkAuth()` and that function takes care of stopping execution if correct permissions are not met.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Got it.  Changed it back to what you had done.  I didn't realize that you had made that edit - I thought I had just forgotten to include it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way is to throw a new [`Meteor.Error`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_error). If [not caught](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) it will stop the currently running function, and if it is thrown from a method or a subscription it will appear on the client-side.

```
function checkAuth(user) {
  if(!isAuthenticated(user)) {
    throw new Meteor.Error('not-authenticated', 'Users need to be authenticated to do foo')
  }
}
```

The above thrown error server-side will appear on the client with the reason and the details. It allows you to do custom error handling tailored to whatever is happening. If any other kind of error is thrown, it will appear as "500 Internal server error".

Note that this mechanism is similar to [`check`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/check_package). You could even use a custom [Match pattern](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/matchpatterns) :

```
check(user, MyPatterns.authenticatedUser)
```